# Как добавить в grub Windows 10, если ее загрузчик был удален?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, grub

## Как добавить в grub Windows 10, если ее загрузчик был удален?

### Доброго времени суток.

На днях решил установить Ubuntu 16.04, на винт по соседству с Windows 10. Результат меня не обрадовал:

Сначала загрузчик винды не пускал меня в убунту, для винды ее просто не существовало,после чего я решил его снести и затем возиться с grub-ом.
После произведенных манипуляций с загрузчиками, в убунту я таки попал, но пути назад не было - возможность посетить чудесный мир Windows 10 исчезла вместе с загрузчиком, на место которого встал grub,и 80% винта стали не доступны.
В течении нескольких часов пытался найти возможность добавить в grub Windows 10, тушка которой так и занимает место на диске, но не найдя решения данной проблемы, решил задать вопрос.

Установка производилась вручную.

Grub заместил собой загрузчик Windows,оставив от него только название директории.

Попытка найти Windows грабом, при помощи os-prober провалилась.
os-prober не смог найти винду.

https://pp.vk.me/c638518/v638518813/19d06/hxs1WsUpDCk.jpg Grub Customizer

https://pp.vk.me/c638518/v638518813/19c9b/0pie-UFliTk.jpg разметка винта

Comment: Я так понимаю, что сохранность конфигурации и софта в windows уже не важна?

Comment: @donRumata Важна, но к сожалению поздно об этом подумал, да и не нашел, как решить проблему с загрузчиком винды...
Есть ли возможность восстановить загрузчик или настроить загрузку в grub?

Comment: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub` не помогает?

Comment: @donRumata https://pp.vk.me/c638518/v638518813/19e28/NN3Azuhw7cY.jpg

Comment: все по-прежнему...

Comment: @donRumata А если попробовать поставить загрузчик винды через восстановление с флешки? Должно сработать?

Comment: Ну, это должно убить граб.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему "гениально": временно залил ubuntu на другой винт, а винду просто "обновил"(поставил на свою винду другую десятку т.к. загрузчик очень не хотел восстанавливаться)